List out printers in tableview which are connected to the same network
I am creating a app for the feature of print photo, scan document and print, documents, large posters, copy live text and print, everything is working as expected. Now i want to enlist the printers in the UITableView which are connected to the same network.  Following is my code for Printer.
let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared

class PrinterManager: NSObject, UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate, UIPrinterPickerControllerDelegate {
    
    let printerPickerController = UIPrinterPickerController(initiallySelectedPrinter: nil)
    
    static let shared = PrinterManager()
    private var viewController: UIViewController?
    var didFinishPrintingClosure: (() -> Void)?
    
    private override init() {}
    
    // Set the view controller when initializing the PrinterManager
    func setViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
        self.viewController = viewController
        self.printerPickerController.delegate = self
    }
}

This is for printer selection method:
func selectPrinter(sender: UIView, successCompletion: @escaping (Bool) -> (), errorCompletion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                self.printerPickerController.present(from: sender.frame, in: self.viewController?.view ?? UIView(), animated: true) { (PickerVC, success, error) in
                    if success && error == nil {
                        if let printerUrl = PickerVC.selectedPrinter?.url {
                            let printerUrlPersistent = printerUrl.absoluteString
                            AppConstants.selectedPrinter = PickerVC.selectedPrinter
                            AppConstants.printerNamePersistent = PickerVC.selectedPrinter?.displayName
                            AppConstants.printerUrlPersistent = printerUrlPersistent
                            successCompletion(true)
                        } else {
                            errorCompletion(true)
                        }
                    } else {
                        errorCompletion(true)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                self.printerPickerController.present(animated: true) { PickerVC, success, error in
                    if let selectedPrinter = PickerVC.selectedPrinter {
                        if let printerUrl = selectedPrinter.url as? URL { // crash
                            let printerUrlPersistent = printerUrl.absoluteString
                            AppConstants.selectedPrinter = selectedPrinter
                            AppConstants.printerNamePersistent = selectedPrinter.displayName
                            AppConstants.printerUrlPersistent = printerUrlPersistent
                            successCompletion(true)
                        } else {
                            errorCompletion(true)
                        }
                    } else {
                        errorCompletion(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

Appreciate in advance for any help.

There is no simple way to discover all of the printers. That is why Apple provides UIPrinterPickerController for letting the user select an AirPrint printer.
